# create a binary if it worked in a time range python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with id, started work time and finished worked time. A worker can work n times per day. This is an example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
id = ['Elton', 'Jose', 'Davis', 'Elton']
started_work_time = ['09:23', '10:32', '09:11', '10:45']
finished_work_time= ['10:10', '11:00', '21:30', '11:00']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':id, 'started_work_hours':started_work_time, 'finished_work_time':finished_work_time}, index=id)
df['started_work_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_work_time'])
df['finished_work_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['finished_work_time'])
print(df)

 id      started_work_hours    finished_work_time
Elton              09:23              10:10
Jose               10:32              11:01
Davis              09:11              10:30
Elton              10:45              11:07
```

What I need is to create a dataframe with binary 1-0 if the id worked during a range of 20 minutes, starting at 9 until 11:20, so for instance Jose worked from 10:32 until 11:01 so, he is in the range 10:20 - 10:40 and 10:40 - 11:00 :

```
id        9:00  9:20 9:40 10:00 10:20 10:40 11:00 
Elton      0     1    1     1     0     0     0
Jose       0     0    0     0     1     1     1
Davis      1     1    1     1     1     0     0
Elton      0     0    0     0     0     1     1
```

I'm starting recently in python so I don't know even how to start, Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: here's a hint to get you started: the datetime.datetime object can be subtracted one from another to get you a datetime.timedelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the question, `print(df)` is slightly different than the sample `df` code. Just for clarity, this is the sample `df` I used:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['Elton', 'Jose', 'Davis', 'Elton'], 'started_work_time':['09:23', '10:32', '09:11', '10:45'], 'finished_work_time':['10:10', '11:01', '10:30', '11:07']}).set_index('id').apply(pd.to_datetime)

#          started_work_time   finished_work_time
# id
# Elton  2021-04-27 09:23:00  2021-04-27 10:10:00
# Jose   2021-04-27 10:32:00  2021-04-27 11:01:00
# Davis  2021-04-27 09:11:00  2021-04-27 10:30:00
# Elton  2021-04-27 10:45:00  2021-04-27 11:07:00
```

First create a 20-min interval date range to later use as columns:

```py
start = df.min().min().floor('20min')
end = df.max().max().floor('20min')
columns = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='20min')

# DatetimeIndex(['2021-04-27 09:00:00', '2021-04-27 09:20:00',
#                '2021-04-27 09:40:00', '2021-04-27 10:00:00',
#                '2021-04-27 10:20:00', '2021-04-27 10:40:00',
#                '2021-04-27 11:00:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='20T')
```

And create a function to test if a given column is between each started/finished pair:

```py
def working(column):
    after_started = column.name >= df.loc[column.index, 'started_work_time'].dt.floor('20min')
    before_finished = column.name <= df.loc[column.index, 'finished_work_time'].dt.floor('20min')
    return after_started & before_finished
```

Then `apply()` it on an empty dataframe shell:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=columns).apply(working).astype(int)
out.index = out.index.map(df.id)

#        09:00:00  09:20:00  09:40:00  10:00:00  10:20:00  10:40:00  11:00:00
# Elton         0         1         1         1         0         0         0
# Jose          0         0         0         0         1         1         1
# Davis         1         1         1         1         1         0         0
# Elton         0         0         0         0         0         1         1
```